# Include value in link- knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to create a link like this schema:

```
<a href="#" data-page="item=2828">Test</a>
```

I´m using this values:

```
                 {
                    id: 1
                    , details: 'item=2828'
                    , dependsOn: []
                    , links: [
                             {
                             label: 'data'
                             , url: '#'
                             }
                          ]
                    },
```

This is my code so far:

```
 <a data-bind="attr: { href: url, 'data-page': details }, click: function(){

  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',$parent.title, label, url, details]);

  return true;

  }, "></a>
```

How can I get the `data-page="text: details"` included?

Comment: The same way you got the href included. It's just another attr value so add it to your attr bindings.

Comment: Alright I´ve added a 'data-something' attr. Is this correct? How can I get this value combined with "data-page=?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Why would you use "data-something" when you want "data-page"? It's going to render whatever you put there as the attribute on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The attr binding provides a generic way to set the value of any attribute for the associated DOM element. This is useful, for example, when you need to set the title attribute of an element, the src of an img tag, or the href of a link based on values in your view model, with the attribute value being updated automatically whenever the corresponding model property changes.

-http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

So to get an attribute on your anchor tag like `data-page="some value"` your binding should look like `data-bind="attr: { 'data-page': 'some value'}"`.

Combining that with your existing data and bindings you should get:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
    details: 'item=2828',
    url: '#Test'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<a data-bind="attr: { href: url, 'data-page': details }">Test link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In your example the 'data-page': details doesn´t working, or? At least they aren´t included in the link. This is my problem at the moment.

Comment: If you run the snippet, and then right-click on the link and inspect its properties you'll see the rendered data-page attribute exists on the element in addition to the original binding. `<a data-bind="attr: { href: url, 'data-page': details }" href="#Test" data-page="item=2828">Test link</a>`

Comment: It's not clear to me what else you're expecting to see. Do you want the link text to change?

Comment: Now it´s working, my mistake. Thank your for your help.This is exactly what i needed.